# Parallel.ForEach vs regular Thread loop

Tags: .net, task, pcap.net

I want to write application using `Pcap.Net` DLL's.
My application get several `PCAP` files and sent all the packets.
Now i want to add the option to send more than 1 files concurrent and wonder what is the best\efficient way to do that.
I have this Collection of files that my application gets and i was thinking about use `Parallel.ForEach` with `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` property or maybe is it other way that i can use and will be useful.

Comment: A couple questions, how big are the files? Also what are you doing with them? If they are small and there is no requirement to use parallel, I wouldn't.

Comment: Are you uploading them via HTTP or what? Can you post a code sample

Comment: It all depends on what you are doing with the files when your program "gets" one. Please explain more what you are doing to the incoming files, if all you do is write them to a disk then making it parallel will make the whole thing slower, not faster, due to the overhead costs being more than the benefit you will get. However if you are doing any kind of CPU bound work doing it in parallel may help.

Comment: Parallel is useful, but be aware that it is a multi threaded method so vars being accessed from a different thread is a real issue

Answer (score 0):

You can use BlockingCollection and start multiple worker threads to keep watch on this BlockingCollection. You use GetConsumingEnumerable method of BockingCollection to start multiple worker threads. As and when the files are available you add it to BlockingCollection, then one of the worker thread pick the file for processing. You can see the details here:  http://mikehadlow.blogspot.in/2012/11/using-blockingcollection-to-communicate.html